# Как создать публичную переменную в классе javascript?

Tags: javascript, классы, конструктор, ecmascript-6

Мне нужно создать класс, но по какой то причине не могу понять как сделать публичные переменные. Мне нужны некоторое переменные к которым я бы постоянно обращался из различных методов в экземпляре класса, а так же мог иметь к ним доступ из вне. Делаю вот так:

```
 class testmaps
{
    var lat=88;
    var lon=55;
     mapStart(container) {
      alert(container+this.lat+this.lon);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Браузер пишет Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier и подчеркивает  var lat.
Что я не так делаю, как надо?

Comment: вам же именно нужно использовать переменную данного класса? тогда this.lat и this.lon

Comment: @Ajmda не в этом суть проблемы, а в том что не могу объявить эти переменные

Comment: тогда замените var на this. this.lat = 88 и тд

Comment: @Ajmda, простая замена не поможет - будет синтаксическая ошибка. их объявление должно быть в конструкторе

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, возьму на заметку

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можете объявлять их в конструкторе

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 88;
        this.b = 55;
    }
    method() { return `${this.a} / ${this.b}`}
}
```

Comment: и это пока единственный метод

Answer (score 1):

В [ECMAScript proposals](https://github.com/tc39/proposals)(предложения на то чтобы добавить возможности в ECMAScript) [stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposals#stage-3)(большая вероятность попасть в реализ) есть предложение о том чтобы добавить в классы публичные и приватные [свойства](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) и [методы](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods), а также публичные и приватные [статические поля и методы](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features/).

Выглядит это вот так:

```js
class MyClass {
    a = 'hi'
    true = false
    static b = 3
}

const instance = new MyClass()

console.log(instance.a, instance['true'], MyClass.b)
```

Более сложный пример:

```
class Counter extends HTMLElement {
  #xValue = 0;

  get #x() { return #xValue; }
  set #x(value) {
    this.#xValue = value; 
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.#render.bind(this));
  }

  #clicked() {
    this.#x++;
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onclick = this.#clicked.bind(this);
  }

  connectedCallback() { this.#render(); }

  #render() {
    this.textContent = this.#x.toString();
  }
}
window.customElements.define('num-counter', Counter);
```

Это все можно использовать уже сегодня благодаря babel и его [preset-stage-3](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-3)!